# ng-model variable stays undefined in controller after all the tries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

everybody!
I've started using ionic with angular recently and tried to write a login form. Used some tutorial, but I can't make it work.

To start with, I searched through stackoverflow for this issue. Other topics contain advises like using a dot, when referring to ng-model. Or problems described differ from mine a bit - i.e using e-mail type for input field.
My reference to ng-model in **login.html** has a dot in it (user.username, user.password):

```
<ion-view view-title="Enter username" name="login-view">
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" 
            ng-model="user.username" >
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" 
            ng-model="user.password">
        </label>          
    </div>
<button class="button button-block button-calm" 
ng-click="login()" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">Login</button>
</ion-content>
```

Main **index.html** has all the used *.js listed.
In my **app.js** I have

```
var quest = angular.module('quest', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);
```

and in **controllers.js** I have

```
quest.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, LoginService, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $state){
$scope.user = {};   
$scope.login = function(){
    alert($scope.user.username + "\n" +
                $scope.user.password);
    LoginService.loginUser($scope.user.username,
                $scope.user.password).success(function(user) {
        alert("admin logged on");
    }).error(function(user) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Inrorrect login/password!',
            template: 'Invalid credentials!'
        });
    });
}
console.log("Logged on as '" + $scope.user.username + 
    "', using pswd '" + $scope.user.password);
});
```

I also use service to check entered credentials, but I don't think that it's to blame.

Controller runs after clicking the button in login form. Right after that I get an alert with undefined variables, and they get to log as undefined either.
I'm really stuck and a bit frustrated). Pls guyz, help!
Maybe should I reinitialize my module in every other file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are `ngApp` and `ngController` correctly setted? Any error in `console`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you binded the controller only to the button element:

```
<button class="button button-block button-calm" 
ng-click="login()" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">Login</button>
```

You must bind the controller with the element surrounding all the code that you want to be a part of it's scope like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Enter username" name="login-view">
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl"> <!-- Here -->
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" 
                ng-model="user.username" >
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" 
                ng-model="user.password">
            </label>          
        </div>
        <button class="button button-block button-calm" 
        ng-click="login()">Login</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```